# How to get filename without version part and replace with older versions?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a folder containing new jar files and I need to replace them on the old version files on a different folder, need to replace even if the version is same.

My sample file name:

```
SC_S_SyncUp_V3.0.0-a7 20211221.jar 
gudusoft.gsqlparser-2.3.0.9.jar
```

When I try with below command, it is getting only the first part "SC".

```
ls | cut -d "_" -f 1
SC
```

Can anyone please guide how to do this.

Comment: [Please don't parse the output of `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Answer (score 0):

If you use "ls -1", "ls" will put each file on a line.  Then a "for loop" would process each filename.  "basename" can remove known suffixes, or you can use "sed" to remove everything past the last ".".

Putting it all together would be:

```
for file in $(ls -1)
do 
    f=$(echo $file | sed 's/\.[^\.]*$//')
    echo $f; 
done
```

I'm not sure what you want to do with "replace with older versions".

Comment: not suffix, _V3.0.0-a7 20211221.jar part in SC_S_SyncUp_V3.0.0-a7 20211221.jar  and -2.3.0.9.jar part in gudusoft.gsqlparser-2.3.0.9.jar part